# Add focus to input with jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Why doesnt this code work? If i replace the focus setting row to a test alert, that works.

```
$('#rendeles_termek').on('change', function() {
    $('#rendeles_mennyiseg').focus();
});
```

```html
<select  name="rendeles_termek" class="form-control chosen-select" id="rendeles_termek">

<input class="form-control" id="rendeles_mennyiseg" name="rendeles_mennyiseg" type="text" value="<?php echo isset($_POST["rendeles_mennyiseg"])?$_POST["rendeles_mennyiseg"]:""; ?>"/>
```

UPDATE:
This works. If i take it out of the onchange, and only into the docu ready.

```
$(document).ready(function(e) { $('#rendeles_mennyiseg').focus();
                    $('#rendeles_termek').on('change', function() {
                         //$('#rendeles_mennyiseg').focus();
                         //alert("xxx");
                      });
                });
```

**UPDATE 2:**

```
<select  name="rendeles_termek" class="form-control chosen-select" id="rendeles_termek">
                    <?php
                    $ertek = isset($_POST["rendeles_termek"]) ? $_POST["rendeles_termek"] : '' ;
                    $get_gyartok = mysqli_query($kapcs, "SELECT termek_id, termek_nev, termek_egyseg FROM termek WHERE termek_status = 1 
                    ORDER BY termek_nev ASC");
                    if(mysqli_num_rows($get_gyartok) > 0 )
                    {
                        while($gy = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_gyartok))
                        {
                            $selected = $ertek == $gy['termek_id'] ? ' selected="selected"':'';
                            echo '<option ' . $selected . ' value="' . $gy['termek_id'] . '">' . $gy['termek_nev'] . ' - ('.$egysegek[$gy['termek_egyseg']].')</option>';
                        }
                    } 
                    ?>
                    </select>

<input class="form-control" id="rendeles_mennyiseg" name="rendeles_mennyiseg" type="text" value="<?php echo isset($_POST["rendeles_mennyiseg"])?$_POST["rendeles_mennyiseg"]:""; ?>"/>
```

Comment: If you fix the HTML so that the `select` has a closing tag and some `option` elements, it works absolutely fine: https://jsfiddle.net/xzexnzr0/

Comment: you haven't closed your `<select>`

Comment: Kindly, post full HTML for select tag. Thanks.

Comment: I copied the full code in my first post.

Comment: Is your code In $(document).ready  method or just before </body> tag?

Comment: what error are you receiving in console?

Comment: What does PHP have to do with this?  When you debug, how specifically does this fail?  I'm unable to replicate the problem, as also pointed out by another user's jsFiddle example above.

Comment: Yes it is document ready, and i dont get no errors.

Comment: Can you share the link where you are hosting this code? It should work.

Comment: alert any thing and then check whether it is triggering the onchange event or not?

Comment: Yes, alert works!

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#rendeles_termek').on('change', function() {
  $('#rendeles_mennyiseg').focus();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="rendeles_termek" class="form-control chosen-select" id="rendeles_termek">
  <option>Option1 </option>
  <option>Option2 </option>
</select>

<input class="form-control" id="rendeles_mennyiseg" name="rendeles_mennyiseg" type="text" placeholder="Focus Me" />
```

I hope this helps you out.

Comment: The focus doent work, but a test alert works. Dont know, whats going on here.

Comment: Focus is working kindly check once. Downvoter kindly explain the reason.

Comment: @slacker: What does changing the quotes do?  In PHP you can use single quotes or double quotes for strings.  There are differences between them, but none of those differences apply here.

Comment: Okay. Actually I'm into JS. So I thought that might be the problem. I'll update my answer. Thanks for informing.

Comment: Is there something, maybe in bootstrap, that disabelds focus?

Comment: blur() function

Comment: The problem is with the chosen select plugin. If i get it off from this selct, the code will work.

Comment: If you can provide a fiddle, then I can look at it.

Comment: The problem is with the chosen select plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem with the code below:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

                      $('#rendeles_termek').on("change", function() {
                           setTimeout(function(ev) { 
                                $('#rendeles_mennyiseg').focus(); }, 
                           1);
                      });


                });
```